# Any opensource project related to Cloud/SOAstarting up?

Tags: java, cloud, soa

I get some spare time [2/3 hrs daily and weekend ofcourse] which i want to invest on working on some opensource project particularly related to SOA , cloud techs ,,Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Apache Nuvem , there seems to be lots of work :
http://wiki.apache.org/incubator/Nuvem

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Java Parallel Processing Framework](http://jppf.org/) is a really cool tech, especially if you like cloud tech.  From the home page:

- a JPPF grid can be up and running in minutes
- dynamically scalable on-demand
- connectors with leading J2EE application servers
- connector with GigaSpaces eXtreme Application Platform
- easy programming model
- fine-grained monitoring and administration
- fault-tolerance and self-repair capabilities
- exceptional level of service and reliability
- fully documented samples, using JPPF on real-life problems
- flexible open-source licensing with Apache 2.0

It also has a cool GUI console so you can monitor nodes:

[image]
[image]